# Difference between video capture read and grab

Tags: python, opencv

I'm not doing nothing in particular, but i'm reading the opencv documentation and I can't understand the difference between the method `read` and `grab` from the `VideoCapture`, here this what they do:

> grab: The methods/functions grab the next frame from video file or
>   camera and return true (non-zero) in the case of success.
>
> read: decodes and returns the next video frame.

In the two method extract the next frame. what is the difference? [Link to the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's a subtle yet significant difference that becomes more obvious when taking a closer look at the documentation for each of the two methods.

- [**`grab`**](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-grab) "only" gets the image from the camera and holds it for further processing:

  > The methods/functions grab the next frame from video file or camera and **return true (non-zero) in the case of success**. [...] you call `VideoCapture::grab()` for each camera and after that call the slower method `VideoCapture::retrieve()` to decode and get frame from each camera.

  In this case, you still have to retrieve the frame (i.e. "decode and get") from OpenCV so that you can work with it. `grab` only returns a boolean that indicates whether OpenCV was able to get the frame from the camera - the return parameter in this case is *not* the frame.
- [**`read`**](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read) combines both `grab` and `retrieve` operations into one command and returns the already decoded frame:

  > The methods/functions combine `VideoCapture::grab()` and `VideoCapture::retrieve()` in one call. This is the most convenient method for reading video files or capturing data from decode and **return the just grabbed frame**. If no frames has been grabbed (camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file), the methods return false and the functions return NULL pointer.

  This method returns the actual frame back to your application so you don't have to worry about checking the boolean parameter and writing an additional line of code to get the frame back by OpenCV.

Depending on your application it may be easier to just use `read` as it will likely save you one or two lines of code.

Answer (score 9):

Adding some info on accepted answer: Also reading from openCV documentation, you should use [grab](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ae38c2a053d39d6b20c9c649e08ff0146) if you need to synchronize images from different devices and don't have triggers connecting cameras.

`grab()` takes less time than `read()`, so you should `grab()` all devices (reading times would be closer) and them `retrieve()` each frame later. Again, this is useful f you need your feeds synchronized, for applications like a custom made stereo camera.

```
    while True:
      # grab all devices
      device1.grab()
      device2.grab()
      ...
      # retrieve them later
      device1.retrieve(frame_dev1)
      device2.retrieve(frame_dev2)
      ...
```